# ServiceStack cache to include object/software version number

Tags: caching, servicestack

I continually burn myself when I'm testing a change to my Servicestack service, say using the browser interface.  I don't see my new changes and it turns out it's because the data is cached.  So I clear the cache and all is well.

I'm wondering if anyone has somehow included a build/version number in their cache keys, OR perhaps done something to clear the cache as part of the deploy process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is good but it requires changes to both Inbound and Outbound DTOs, and exposes a parameter to the end user of the service that he might not care about (because it's more of an implementation detail).  I was hoping for something a that was entirely internal.

I ended up making sure my AssemblyVersion attribute was set to change Revision/Build numbers on every build:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Then I created the following helper class to pull that version number out as a string:

```
internal class AssemblyVersion
    {
        public static string Version
        {
            get
            {
                return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
```

finally, I add the version number to every inbound DTO's Cachekey property.  Now the DLL version number is stored as part of the Cache key, and new builds of the DLL makes sure to not use old version cache entries.

```
[DataContract]
[Route("/cachedhello/{Name}")]
public class CachedHello : IReturn<string>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string CacheKey
    {
    get
       {
          return string.Format("urn:cachedhello:nm={0}:ver={1}", Name, AssemblyVersion.Version);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool nice strategy not to mix caches from different builds together, but I'd normally just flush the cache after a deployment myself.

Comment: Your idea is better.  I even found a great hook to do it!  I created a cache-clearing service, then added a call to it in the <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish> setting of the .pubxml file.

Answer (score 3):

I'd typically just include a `Created` DateTime embedded in the Response DTO with the Utc Date of when the Response DTO was created and cached. I normally also include a `Reload` flag in the Request DTO to indicate whether I want to force a new cache or not.

You can find an example of this in [TechStacks Example](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacks/blob/7501b0ddc2dd7eade3919d4f42a4367f58196855/src/TechStacks/TechStacks.ServiceModel/TechnologyStacks.cs#L19-L40), e.g:

```
[Route("/techstacks/{Slug}", Verbs = "GET")]
public class GetTechnologyStack : IReturn<GetTechnologyStackResponse>
{
    public bool Reload { get; set; }

    public string Slug { get; set; }
}

public class GetTechnologyStackResponse
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public TechStackDetails Result { get; set; }

    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

A basic implementation would look like:

```
public object Get(GetTechnologyStack request)
{
    var key = "{0}/{1}".Fmt(request.GetType().Name,request.Slug);
    if (request.Reload)
        Cache.Remove(key);

    return base.Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(Cache, key, () =>
    {
        //...
        return new GetTechnologyStackResponse {
            Created = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Result = result,
        };
    });
}
```